# Fail to delete whole database in couchbase lite (version 2.0.2) android

Tags: android, couchbase-lite

I'm new in Couchbase lite android. I'm using Couchbase lite version 2.0.2 for my android application. I want to delete the whole database when the user is changed. But I couldn't arrive to do that, I have always the exception: 
CouchbaseLiteException{domain='CouchbaseLite', code=16, msg=Can't delete db file while other connections are open}

I tried to close the database object before deleting it, but there is another exception for closing. Here is my code:

```
    private void initDb(Context context) {
    try{
        Log.d(TAG, "Init database");
        database = new Database(DB_NAME, new DatabaseConfiguration(context));
        if(isDifferentUser()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Delete database");
            database.delete();
            database = null;
            database = new Database(DB_NAME, new DatabaseConfiguration(context));
        }
    } catch (CouchbaseLiteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error initializing db", e);
    }
}
```

And I checked carefully that this code has been called only once since the application is created, I wondered why it said that the other connections were open. Do you know how to delete the whole database in couchbase lite? Thanks

Comment: Queries and replicators will also keep the database open, FYI.

Comment: @borrrden yes, we have to stop the other connections to database. No way to do that, I have to delete directly database file.

Comment: @sophie281988 did u solve this issue

Comment: Any solution on this using Coubaselite 2.7 but issue still persists even with  removal of listeners